# Inverse Gumbel Sampling

Tags: r, inverse, cdf

I'm trying to use the inverse CDF of the Gumbel Dist. to simulate random numbers. However for the inverse I get `mu-x*log(-log(beta))` which spits out imaginary numbers which can't be write. 
The original CDF is `e^-e^(-(x-mu)/beta)`.

And my code is:

```
n=1000 #sample size 
set.seed(1) #Makes the outcomes reproducible 

x = runif(n) # simulate n uniform pseudo-random numbers

fx = 0-x*log(-log(10)) #Runs the pseudo-random numbers through the inverse CDF
```

If anyone can tell where I'm going wrong that would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: This question may be better asked in https://math.stackexchange.com/, since it simplifies to a question re: how do you find the inverse of this CDF (with negative exponents)

Comment: This derivation is found at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374931/how-to-find-the-inverse-transform-of-the-gumbel-distribution

Answer (score 1):

You're simplifying incorrectly. `0-x*log(-log(10))` will always be undefined, no matter what `x`is. This is because you are taking the log of a negative number. A log with an argument greater than 1 will *always be positive (e.g., `log(10)`), making `-log(10)` negative. Pull out the negative signs in the exponents for your CDF first, before taking the log of both sides.

*provided the base is greater than 1

Comment: The argument of the `ln(-ln(U))` part is U~Uniform(0,1) so this evaluates just fine.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374931/how-to-find-the-inverse-transform-of-the-gumbel-distribution.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan when R tries to evaluate the code the OP wrote, it doesn't evaluate fine (because the OP used an argument > 1, specifically, `log(-log(10))`.  Let me clarify, though.

Comment: you're not wrong.  In MATLAB, `log(-log(10)) =  0.8340 + 3.1416i` (complex) and it does fails in R (I just tested).  However, the argument of the `ln(-ln( ))` expression is on the interval [0,1] based on the derivation I posted in the first comment.  I can't find a reason where this argument would be outside that range. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just wanted to clarify for others, this occurs because the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) is a probability and lies on [0,1].  Thus the [inverse transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) (inverse of the CDF) has an argument on [0,1].

Comment: @SecretAgentMan you're not missing something, and I upvoted your answer to the stats.SE question. This answer addresses the code in the OP for the question here, which fails for reasons I think I clarified in my edit to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You transposed the x and beta in the quantile function:

```
 q <- mu-beta*log(-log(x)))
  x = runif(100)

   qgum <- function(x, mu=0, beta=1){ stopifnot(beta > 0);  mu - beta*(log(-log(x))) }
```

That does return real (albeit some negative) values from the runif `argument` but this agrees with the calculation from `actuar::qgumbel`:

```
all.equal( qgumbel(x, 0, 10), qgum(x, 0, 10) )
[1] TRUE
```